# Express Not able to get request body value

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to learn the MEAN stack by following a tutorial for CRUD operations using REST Api with express and mongoose. I am able to run the GET and DELETE operations but I am not getting the POST and PUT operations because I am not getting the required request body values.

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
var todoObject = {
    name: req.body.name
};
Todo.create(todoObject, function (err, todo) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    Todo.find(function (err, todos) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json(todos);
    });
});  });
```

As you can see from the code that I am setting the name parameter of the json object using the request body value which I pass through POSTMAN. A new document is getting created but the name value is unset in the database.
However, giving the name directly works. Please help me.

Comment: Do you use bodyParser?

Comment: Yes, I did use bodyParser.

Comment: Did you try `todoObject = req.body`, with the assumption that your body contains exactly what you intend to put in your db

Comment: Yes, I have tried using `todoObject = req.body` and it did not work. So, I have tried the above method.

Comment: Are you sure your `todoObject` variable has a scope lifetime outside its callback function? Try initializing the variable outside the callback function and see if you still get a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest and safest way is to send JSON object from the client using RAW data.

so ,to implement it follow the steps below:

- **Set the Content/type to application/json in the Headers**
  [image]
- **Select raw type and put your JSON object in the Body**
  [image]
- **And finally Your code should be like:**

  ```
   router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {

      var todoObject = req.body; 

      Todo.create(todoObject, function (err, todo) {

                  if (err) res.send(err);
                  Todo.find(function (err, todos) {
                      if (err) res.send(err);
                      res.json(todos);
                  });
              }); 
           });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Content-Type: application/json` in Headers if it is with JSON format.